# Let $G=U(15) \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{10} \oplus S_5$. Find the order of $(2,3,(123)(15))$. Find the inverse of $(2,3,(123)(15))$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G=U(15) \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{10} \oplus S_5$. Find the order of $(2,3,(123)(15))$. Find the inverse of $(2,3,(123)(15))$.

To find the order I saw the order of the first element would be $15$ and the order of the second element would be $10$ while the order of the last element would be the lcm of the cycle lengths or $6$. So would the order of  $(2,3,(123)(15))$ just then be the lcm of $(15,10,6)$ which would be $30$? Now is there a faster way to find the inverse other then just doing the brute computation work?

Comment: hint: find inverses componentwise.